# Troubles with fonts when compiling

Tags: errors, compiling, texstudio

When I compile document through terminal I get an error:

```
pdflatex file.tex
...
! Font T2A/cmr/m/n/12=larm1200 at 12.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not fo
und.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.105 \fontencoding\encodingdefault\selectfont
```

When I compile it with `sudo` I haven't any errors.

How can I prevent this issue? I work in TeXstudio and I can not use `sudo` there.

OS X El Captain 10.11.1

Comment: You probably have some permission issues. Cyrillic font files for the `cmr` family are produced on demand and stored in `~/Library/texlive/2015/texmf-var`. Possibly a run with `sudo` created the relevant directory structure with superuser privileges. Check it. From a terminal window issue `ls -ld ~/Library/texlive/2015/texmf-var` and report the output.

Comment: @egreg ~/Library/texlive/2015/texmf-var: Permission denied

Comment: `sudo chmod -R 755 ~/Library/texlive/` works for me. Thank you.

Comment: I'd prefer also a `chown`